# Eclipse crashes and closes when using CEF inside eclipse plugin for perspective

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, chromium-embedded

I have developed a eclipse plugin in which I am using Chromium Embedded Framework.
Inside chromium I am launching a page which is hosted on local server(XAMPP).

Now I have generated a 'JAR' of plugin and added in eclipse plugins folder.

When I launch the eclipse the plugin is getting loaded successfully but when I am navigating through the pages inside chromium, sometimes the eclipse crashes and gets closed.

Even, when I am switching between eclipse and other windows application the eclipse crashes and gets closed forcefully.

Comment: read the log file exact reason and update the question. if it crashing on a specific scenario then update that too.

Comment: i will post log....